# Access AWS secret manager over truststore of application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, truststore

I have lambda function in spring boot, and I want to access secret manager and not truststore.
While trying to get access secret manager, application is trying to find for the secret in truststore rather than going to secret manager.
how to solve this?

trying to find if there are any configs that will help me to use both truststore and secret manager.

Comment: What truststore? The Java truststore? The code for accessing the truststore and the code for accessing something in SecretsManager would be completely different, so it is entirely unclear what is happening in your application. You would need to edit your question to include your code, and any relevant logs and error messages, if you want someone here to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I meant java truststore. So I have a java application and it has truststore with few keys related to project. Now I'm adding new feature, where I want to use secret manager to store my secrets. Its erroring out in secrets manager client while trying to access the secret: with error: [sdkclientexception unable to execute http request pkix path building failed: unable to find valid certification path]

Comment: Consider using https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-RC1/reference/html/index.html#spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager to simplify it.